# why is there a while loop in put() of LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, blockingqueue

```
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    int c = -1;
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>(e);
    final ReentrantLock putLock = this.putLock;
    final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
    putLock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (count.get() == capacity) {
            notFull.await();
        }
        enqueue(node);
        c = count.getAndIncrement();
        if (c + 1 < capacity)
            notFull.signal();
    } finally {
        putLock.unlock();
    }
    if (c == 0)
        signalNotEmpty();
}
```

why is there a while loop?

All the putting thread is shut out by putLock.

No thread can increase 'count' when the waiting thread is holding the putLock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fundamental property of `await` (which applies to the intrinsic locking via `synchronized` and using `Object.wait` as well), you have to understand:

When you invoke `await`, you are *releasing the lock* this `Condition` is associated with¹. There is no way around it, as otherwise, no-one could acquire the lock, make the condition fulfilled, and invoke `signal` on it.

When your waiting thread gets signaled, it does not get the lock back immediately. That would not be possible, as the thread which invoked `signal` still owns it. Instead, the receiver will try to re-acquire the lock, not much different to calling `lockInterruptibly()`.

But this thread is not necessarily the only thread trying to acquire the lock. It doesn’t even have to be the first one. Another thread could have arrived at `put` before the signalling and waiting for the lock at `lockInterruptibly()`. So even if the lock was fair (which locks usually are not), the signaled thread had no precedence. Even if you gave signaled threads precedence, there could be multiple threads being signaled for different reasons.

So another thread arriving at `put` could get the lock before the signaled thread, find that there is space, and store the element without ever bothering with signals. Then, by the time the signaled thread acquired the lock, the condition is not fulfilled anymore. So a signaled thread can never rely on the validity of the condition just because it received a signal and therefore has to re-check the condition and invoke `await` again if not fulfilled.

This makes checking the condition in a loop the standard idiom of using `await`, as documented in [the `Condition` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), as well as [`Object.wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) for the case of using the intrinsic monitor, just for completeness. In other words, this is not even specific to a particular API.

Since the condition has to be pre-checked and re-checked in a loop anyway, the specification even allows for *spurious wakeups*, the event of a thread returning from the wait operation without actually receiving a signal. This may simplify lock implementations of certain platforms, while not changing the way a lock has to be used.

¹ It’s important to emphasize that when holding multiple locks, *only* the lock associated with the condition is released.

Comment: I know what a spurious fail is in case of `weakCompareAndSet`, is that the same for *spurious wakeups*? do you happen to know?

Comment: @Eugene I don’t know which particular implementation details the developers had in mind. I vaguely remember having read something about a Linux threading library, but in the end, it doesn’t matter, as the way it works, it may always behave as-if spurious wakeups could happen, i.e. you need the loop anyway.

Comment: Spot on.  spurious wakeups can happen on certain architectures where threads can be awoken without actually receiving the signal.  For example, some architectures awake _all_ conditions when any are signaled because of implementation.

Comment: One thing to point out is that `notFull` is a condition that comes from `putLock` so when you call specifically `notFull.await()`, this unlocks `putLock`.  I know you are saying that but please consider making it more obvious.

Comment: @Gray I think I know where you’re heading at. Added an explicit statement.

Comment: My point was that the OP may not understand that `notFull` and `putLock` are connected.  Instead of talking about `await()`, I would say `notFull.await()` causes the `putLock` to be unlocked....

Comment: @Gray I think, it is enough to emphasize that conditions *are* associated with a lock and will release that lock (and only that lock). Once that is understood, the reader also understands the necessity to know which lock is associated with a condition, to fully understand the source code. For the actual question “why is there a loop”, it is entirely irrelevant which lock is released, in fact, the existence of two locks in this class is a distraction. For beginners, it’s much better to look at `ArrayBlockingQueue`, which has only one `Lock`, but, of course, still needs the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Loop's function(*) is blocking the thread that is called put method when LinkedBlockingQueue's capacity is full. When another thread call take (or poll) method, there will be space for new element in the queue and take method will signal the `notFull` Condition, and the waiting thread will be woken up and can put the item to the queue.

(*) Condition of the loop is for to guarantee that a spurious wakeup did not occured.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup

Comment: I think there is only one thread waiting because of notFull.await().  Not "one of". ?

Comment: @Syn multiple threads can reach that point. But when they are notified, only one of them will be able to continue, others have to wait the next notify, (then again only one of them will continue.)

Comment: why  'multiple threads can reach that point.' ?   One thread can acquire the putLock, others wait because 'putLock.lockInterruptibly()'

Comment: Multiple threads can reach that point.  See @Holger's answer.  `notFull` is a condition attached to `putLock`.  When you call `notFull.awat()` this releases the `putLock` lock @Syn.

Comment: @Gray Thanks. I have not used Conditions before. There is always something to learn I guess.

Answer (score 0):

@Holder's answer is correct but I'd like to add more details about the following code and question.

```
putLock.lockInterruptibly();
try {
    while (count.get() == capacity) {
        notFull.await();
    }
    ...
```

> why is there a while loop?  All the putting thread is shut out by putLock.

The while loop is a critical part of this code pattern that ensures that when the thread is awoken from a signal on `notFull`, it makes sure that another thread didn't get there first and re-fill the buffer.

One thing that it is important to realize that the `notFull` is defined as a condition on `putLock`:

```
private final Condition notFull = putLock.newCondition();
```

When the thread calls `notFull.await()` it will *unlock* `putLock` which means that multiple threads could be running `notFull.await()` at the same time.  A thread will only attempt to reacquire the lock after `notFull.signal()` (or `signalAll()`) is called.

The race condition happens if thread-A is `BLOCKED` trying to acquire `putLock` and thread-B is `WAITING` on `notFull`.  If a thread-C removes something from the queue and signals `notFull`, thread-B will be taken out of the waiting-queue and put into the blocked-queue on `putLock` but unfortunately, it will be *behind* thread-A which was already blocked.  So once `putLock` is unlocked, thread-A will acquire `putLock` and put something into the queue, filling it again.  When thread-B finally acquires `putLock`, it needs to test again to see if there is still space available before putting (and overflowing) the queue.  That's why the `while` is necessary.

A secondary reason for the while loop, as @Holder also mentioned, is to protect against spurious wakeups which can happen under certain thread architectures when a condition gets signaled artificially.  For example, under some architectures, a signal on *any* condition signals *all* conditions because of OS limitations.